# HTML5/razor how to alter length of a input text box

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, html, razor

Why has html5 changed so much stuff!

How do i alter the width of the below two text boxes?

```
  <div class="editor-field">
          @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.S1_LandLine)
          @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.S1_LandLine)
  </div>
```

and

```
  <input type="text" id="myinput" value="1" class="Q" data-id2="Q" />
```

and

```
<select id="S1_TitleID" name="S1_TitleID">
       <option selected="selected" value="1">Mr</option>
       <option value="2">Miss</option>
       <option value="3">Mrs</option>
</select>
```

Comment: this is not HTML5 alone, this is MVC and Razor !

Comment: possible duplicate of [asp.net-mvc How to change width Html.TextBox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1063737/asp-net-mvc-how-to-change-width-html-textbox)

Comment: See linked question, you can use a CSS class then you do it with JQuery ;-)

Comment: @Davide - Don't use jQuery or javascript to do styling ... that's what CSS is for

Comment: not to do styling, but to change the width client side, in case he wants to change it from what is defined in the css class. Question was not clear to me ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using CSS:

```
.editor-field input[type="text"], .editor-field select
{
  width:100px;
}
```

Comment: See the edit, this assumes the select is within the same div with `.editor-field` as class.

Comment: Also; i'd recommend you to learn some basic HTML/CSS. It helps :)

Answer (score 0):

To generate the desired markup:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.S1_LandLine, new { data_id2 = "Q", @class = "Q" })
```

As far as the *length* is concerned (whatever that means) you could use CSS to specify the `Q` rule => nothing really related to ASP.NET MVC nor HTML5.

Answer (score 0):

What exactly did HTML5 change?! I am going to assume by length you mean the `maxlength`, or the number of characters you can input into the text box. I may be wrong but your question is a bit ambiguous.

For the first you can do:

```
<div class="editor-field">  
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.S1_LandLine, new { maxlength = 10 })  
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.S1_LandLine)  
</div>
```

And the second:

```
<input type="text" id="myinput" value="1" class="Q" data-id2="Q" maxlength="10" />
```

If you are not looking the `maxlength` then what are you looking?

EDIT: Just noticed you say the width, if so follow others advice on here.

Answer (score 0):

I know i am a little off topic, but if you're looking for maxlength attribute :

We are using the MVC pattern : your view should be strongly typed to your model.

View

```
<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Rating)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Rating)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Rating)
</div>

<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Body)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Body)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Body)
</div>
```

And in the model, we can set defined conditions :

```
[Required]
[Range(1,10,ErrorMessage="Not in the 1-10 Range"]
public int Rating { get; set; }

[Required]
[StringLength(1024,ErrorMessage="Incorrect format")]
public string Body { get; set; }
```