# Bootstrap 3 & Boostrap 4 & Bootstrap 5 - input-xs (smaller than sm)

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-5

I wasted a lot of time searching a way to make my own xs size (smaller than the small) for input and input group,  ***so here's the code!***

[Peter Butkovic](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1581069/peter-butkovic) upload the bug/request to the bootstrap github:
https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/15107

with the following response from theirs:

> We won't be adding it to v3 and I don't think we'll have the xs
> buttons even in v4, but I'll keep it in mind for that if we opt to
> keep it around.

Still working for Bootstrap 5

Answer (score 104, accepted):

For inputs smallers:

```
.input-xs {
  height: 22px;
  padding: 2px 5px;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 1.5; /* If Placeholder of the input is moved up, rem/modify this. */
  border-radius: 3px;
}
```

Sample usage in input-group:

```
<div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-xs btn-success">
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>
        </button>
    </span>
    <input type="text" class="form-control input-xs" />
    <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-xs btn-danger">
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></i>
        </button>
    </span>
</div>
```

**Alternatively you can add class to the input-group like this one:**

```
.input-group-xs>.form-control,
.input-group-xs>.input-group-addon,
.input-group-xs>.input-group-btn>.btn {
    height: 22px;
    padding: 1px 5px;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 1.5;
}
```

and use:

```
<div class="input-group input-group-xs">
    <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-success">
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>
        </button>
    </span>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" />
    <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-danger">
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></i>
        </button>
    </span>
</div>
```

```css
.input-xs {
  height: 22px!important;
  padding: 2px 5px;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 1.5;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
.input-group-xs>.form-control,
.input-group-xs>.input-group-addon,
.input-group-xs>.input-group-btn>.btn {
  height: 22px;
  padding: 1px 5px;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 1.5;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="input-group">
  <span class="input-group-btn">
    <button class="btn btn-xs btn-success">
      <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>
    </button>
  </span>
  <input type="text" class="form-control input-xs" />
  <span class="input-group-btn">
    <button class="btn btn-xs btn-danger">
      <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></i>
    </button>
  </span>
</div>
<br/>
<div class="input-group input-group-xs">
  <span class="input-group-btn">
    <button class="btn btn-success">
      <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>
    </button>
  </span>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" />
  <span class="input-group-btn">
    <button class="btn btn-danger">
      <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></i>
    </button>
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: I would change the height to 23px. If you zoom to 400% you will see it fits better.

Answer (score 7):

If you are using `bootstrap-sass`, then you can leverage `input-size` mixin:

```
$input-height-xs: 27px; // adjust it according to your theme.

@include input-size('.input-xs', $input-height-xs, $padding-xs-vertical, $padding-xs-horizontal, $font-size-small, $line-height-small, $input-border-radius-small);
```

Comment: I think this must be a comment.

Comment: @LeandroTupone Why, because it is short? I tend to disagree, because it answers the question.

Comment: because is for sass

Comment: I don't see anything new

Comment: That is stated at the beginning. They have an official sass release, v4 is being written in sass. Many people use bootstrap with Sass. So I do not think it is irrelevant. You can still flag the answer if you feel like it is right thing to do.

Comment: I know but is not related for the question, I was thinking more in a definitive solution to this issue