# Bootstrap smaller input and smaller input-group-addon issue

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have used this in my CSS to create an smaller input field:

```
.input-xs {
  height: 22px;
  padding: 2px 5px;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 1.5; /* If Placeholder of the input is moved up, rem/modify this. */
  border-radius: 3px;
}
```

But of course I need to adjust the `input-group-addon` as well or it will look like this.
[image]

To prevent this and make the `input-group-addon` smaller, I have added this to my CSS.

```
.input-group-xs > .form-control,
.input-group-xs > .input-group-addon,
.input-group-xs > .input-group-btn > .btn {
  height: 22px;
  padding: 2px 5px;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 1.5;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
```

But it looks like this now.

[image]

Any suggestions to get it aligned again?

**Complete code**

```
<div class="input-group-xs form-group" id="div_exp_aantal['.$i.']">
  <input type="number" min="0" class="form-control input-xs" id="exp_aantal['.$i.']" name="exp_aantal" placeholder="Huidige aantal" value="'.$row_list['aantal_huidig'].'" onkeyup="validate_exp(this, '.$i.')" onmousemove="validate_exp(this, '.$i.')">
  <span class="input-group-addon">stuk</span>
</div>
```

Comment: You just need to change `.form-group` to `.input-group` in your outer most `div`, [Docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/components/#input-groups-sizing). (Just an FYI: You might want to adjust your **border-radius** rules to apply to independent corners in keeping with the overall framework styling.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bootstrap 3 & Boostrap 4 - input-xs (smaller than sm)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22920589/bootstrap-3-boostrap-4-input-xs-smaller-than-sm)

Comment: @Leandro why are you replying to an post that is almost 3 years old? And has an accepted answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I were you, I'd add the class name "input-group" before the "input-group-xs" in order to add the base css.

```
.input-group {
position: relative;
    display: table;
    border-collapse: separate;
}
```

So your code should look like this:

```
<div class="input-group input-group-xs form-group" id="div_exp_aantal['.$i.']">
  <input type="number" min="0" class="form-control input-xs" id="exp_aantal['.$i.']" name="exp_aantal" placeholder="Huidige aantal" value="'.$row_list['aantal_huidig'].'" onkeyup="validate_exp(this, '.$i.')" onmousemove="validate_exp(this, '.$i.')">
  <span class="input-group-addon">stuk</span>
</div>
```