# Input size smaller than "form-control-sm" in bootstrap 4 e.g. xs?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Is there a class to use to size dropdowns, input fields etc with something smaller than form-control-sm?  I don't see any, so custom class is needed?

I'm using the CDN for bootstrap4 css and want to use a default font size of .75em for all text, but the bootstrap inputs are getting rendered at .875em.

What is a good way to override this and make them match?

Comment: you can change it by overriding css

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bootstrap 3 & Boostrap 4 - input-xs (smaller than sm)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22920589/bootstrap-3-boostrap-4-input-xs-smaller-than-sm)